# Python + Windows: How to write a script that pops up a reminder on computer sleep/shutdown?

Tags: python, windows

I want to write a Python script that will remind me to take my medicine on sleep/shutdown.
(just a simple pop up message). Where do I begin?

(I'm looking for a really simple implementation if it exists. I don't want to put too much effort into this)

Comment: Must it be a python script? I'm sure there is a very simple registry key to edit to achieve this.

Comment: I'm with @AntiEarth on this one. Using Python to do this is analogous to using a pocket knife as a paperweight.

Comment: Thanks. Will open it for other options in a new question. If it's really easier I will go with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will tell you how to detect event
Linux:- [Detect user logout / shutdown in Python / GTK under Linux - SIGTERM/HUP not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490166/detect-user-logout-shutdown-in-python-gtk-under-linux-sigterm-hup-not-rece).
Windows :- [Python - Windows Shutdown Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events)

And this will pop up notice

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Take your Medicine \n :):)...Get Well Soon...")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```