# windows - how to write a script that pops up a reminder on shutdown

Tags: windows

I want to write a simple script that will remind me to take my medicine on shutdown/sleep.
How do I begin? (looking for the easiest way)

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022670/python-windows-how-to-write-a-script-that-pops-up-a-reminder-on-computer-slee/12022738#12022738 from earlier today?

Comment: Yes, but I asked about python and got a specific response about python. I got some comments that there are easier ways, so I'm asking a new question. (didn't want to edit the old question cause I got some good answers)