# "socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused" when attempting to monitor ACPI event in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tablet, monitor, acpi

I am attempting to monitor ACPI events in order to detect when the screen on a [ThinkPad S1 Yoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Yoga) has been folded over (turning a laptop into a tablet). What I'm watching for is the following, which indicates that the screen position has been toggled:

```
sudo acpi_listen
ibm/hotkey HKEY 00000080 000060c0
```

I'm very new to this, but following [online instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=646012#2) and [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530331/1556092), I am attempting to monitor ACPI events in Python using the module [socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), but I'm running into difficulties:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect("/var/run/acpid.socket")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I would appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: I copied your code in a python console and i don't get any error... strange. Could be some permission problem?